# How to achieve this title generation from this website

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve something similar to the way the heading of a page is presented to the user of this website with jQuery, i.e.:

http://wonder-wall.com/#project/en

when you click on a thumbnail from the main index, the heading of that thumbnail generates different values until it appears to the user properly.

Just wondering if this can be achieved somehow using jQuery even though it is using Adobe Flash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an approach without jQuery. I am sure this can be improved, but I hope this helps and gives you an idea of how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function createRandomString(length, id, callback, value) {
    if (typeof value == "undefined"){
        value = "";
    }
    if (value.length == length){        
        callback(value);
        return;
    }
    var c = ((Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % 127);
    if (c == '\'' || c == '\"'){
        c = 33;
    }
    value += String.fromCharCode(Math.max(33, c));
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    setTimeout(function(){createRandomString(length, id, callback, value)}, 20);
}

   function changeHeader(id, realString, randomString){
      if (typeof randomString == "undefined") {
        createRandomString(realString.length, id, function(value){changeHeader(id, realString, value);});
        return;
      }
      var d = realString.length - randomString.length;
      var modifiedString  = realString.substring(0, d) + randomString;
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = modifiedString;
      if (randomString.length == 0){
        return;
        }
      randomString = randomString.substring(1);
      setTimeout(function(){changeHeader(id,realString,randomString);}, 50);
    }


</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="test"></h1>

<button onclick="changeHeader('test', 'this is the header')">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Moxn - works great. Will go through your code to understand your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Although moxn has done all the hard work for you, I suppose what you are really after is a jquery-fied version of that...

So here is a jquery plugin, thanks moxn for original code, all I did was convert it to a jquery plugin

```
(function($){
  $.fn.generateHeader=function(settings){
    var settings=$.extend({
      newText:"This is a new header"
    },settings);
    return this.each(function(){
      var _this=$(this)[0];

      changeHeader(_this, settings.newText);

      function createRandomString(length, node, callback, value) {
        if (typeof value == "undefined"){
          value = "";
        }
        if (value.length == length){                
          callback(value);
          return;
        }
        var c = ((Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % 127);
        if (c == '\'' || c == '\"'){
          c = 33;
        }
        value += String.fromCharCode(Math.max(33, c));
        node.innerHTML = value;
        setTimeout(function(){createRandomString(length, node, callback, value)}, 20);
      }

     function changeHeader(node, realString, randomString){
      if (typeof randomString == "undefined") {
        createRandomString(realString.length, node, function(value){changeHeader(node, realString, value);});
        return;
      }
      var d = realString.length - randomString.length;
      var modifiedString  = realString.substring(0, d) + randomString;
      node.innerHTML = modifiedString;
      if (randomString.length == 0){
        return;
        }
      randomString = randomString.substring(1);
      setTimeout(function(){changeHeader(node,realString,randomString);}, 50);
    }




    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You would use it by first including the above code somewhere in your html...

and then calling something like `$('#heading').generateHeader({newText:'this is the new header text'});` where `heading` is the id of the element you would want to apply this to, and then change `'this is the new header text'` to whatever text you would want to show up...

Comment: Thanks ekhaled for jQuerying Moxn's version.